# How to update a modalViewController after another modalViewController has exited

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, modalviewcontroller

I have a view that is presented when a user clicks on a button (a UIModalPresentationFormSheet).  This view has 4 text fields on them, and one button that when clicked pops another (UIModalPresentationFormSheet) view on top.  The only thing that this view has is a picker.  When an entry is picked, the user then goes back to the previous view.  I want to display this entry on the original view after this, but I'm not sure how to update the previous view since the method "ViewWillAppear" and "ViewDidAppear" are not called.  Is there a way to send an event to the original modal view when a modal view on top has exited?  This way I can update the text of a label from the original once that picker view is discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use delegation.